# How to isolate certain letters inside a string in R?

Tags: r, string

**I need to find an index** *for all the values that present Q2 or Q4*.

So basically skipping the first element that is a title. I need to save: 3,5,7,9..... till the end of the object.

How can I do this analyzing a string?

This is the code:

```
 line = c("ISSUE_CUR", "1993-Q1", "1993-Q2", "1993-Q3", "1993-Q4", "1994-Q1", 
"1994-Q2", "1994-Q3", "1994-Q4", "1995-Q1", "1995-Q2", "1995-Q3", 
"1995-Q4", "1996-Q1", "1996-Q2", "1996-Q3", "1996-Q4", "1997-Q1", 
"1997-Q2", "1997-Q3", "1997-Q4", "1998-Q1", "1998-Q2", "1998-Q3", 
"1998-Q4", "1999-Q1", "1999-Q2", "1999-Q3", "1999-Q4", "2000-Q1", 
"2000-Q2", "2000-Q3", "2000-Q4", "2001-Q1", "2001-Q2", "2001-Q3", 
"2001-Q4", "2002-Q1", "2002-Q2", "2002-Q3", "2002-Q4", "2003-Q1", 
"2003-Q2", "2003-Q3", "2003-Q4", "2004-Q1", "2004-Q2", "2004-Q3", 
"2004-Q4", "2005-Q1", "2005-Q2", "2005-Q3", "2005-Q4", "2006-Q1", 
"2006-Q2", "2006-Q3", "2006-Q4", "2007-Q1", "2007-Q2", "2007-Q3", 
"2007-Q4", "2008-Q1", "2008-Q2", "2008-Q3", "2008-Q4", "2009-Q1", 
"2009-Q2", "2009-Q3", "2009-Q4", "2010-Q1", "2010-Q2", "2010-Q3", 
"2010-Q4", "2011-Q1", "2011-Q2", "2011-Q3", "2011-Q4", "2012-Q1", 
"2012-Q2", "2012-Q3", "2012-Q4", "2013-Q1", "2013-Q2", "2013-Q3", 
"2013-Q4", "2014-Q1", "2014-Q2", "2014-Q3", "2014-Q4", "2015-Q1", 
"2015-Q2", "2015-Q3", "2015-Q4", "2016-Q1", "2016-Q2", "2016-Q3", 
"2016-Q4", "2017-Q1", "2017-Q2", "2017-Q3", "2017-Q4", "2018-Q1", 
"2018-Q2", "2018-Q3", "2018-Q4", "2019-Q1", "2019-Q2", "2019-Q3", 
"2019-Q4")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep` to return the index by matching 'Q2' or (`|`) 'Q4' at the end (`$`) of the string

```
grep("(Q2|Q4)$", line)
#[1]   3   5   7   9  11  13  15  17  19  21  23  25  27  29  31  33  35  37  39  41  43  45  47  49  51  53  55  57  59  61
#[31]  63  65  67  69  71  73  75  77  79  81  83  85  87  89  91  93  95  97  99 101 103 105 107 109
```

Or the 'Q' can be placed outside as it is common

```
grep("Q(2|4)$", line)
```

---

Or another option is `endsWith`

```
which(endsWith(line, "Q2")|endsWith(line, "Q4"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the grep() function.

```
grep("[24]$", line, value = T)
```

The "[24]$" is a regular expression pattern. For a good tutorial on it, you may check here.
https://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html

Comment: I will check this thanks. But let's say I have a pattern where I have Q2, Q4, Q24, and I want to extract all the string that presents Q24. How Can you specify this?

Comment: grep("Q24$", line, value = T) will bring only Q24 and nothing else. Check the tutorial, it will explain everything.